# Why do we have "finance" tag for math.SE

Tags: discussion, tagging

I saw there is a [finance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance) tag in math.SE, and people are allowed to ask directly finance questions in math.SE. Curious why?

Although finance questions could need math calculations, a lot of other backgrounds/conversions/terms might get involved. Plus the way finance question is asked usually is not the same as mathematics, and thus you need to switch context a bit in understanding the questions and terms.

Why don't we have a separate board for finance? And if someone needs to ask math involved in finance, he/she could abstract the math out and ask in math.SE without involving any finance context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think tags like [finance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance) and [physics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics) are OK so long as the questions are primarily about the mathematics and that any jargon used is completely explained.  For example, a question about loan payments may be, from a mathematics perspective, primarily about geometric series and would therefore fall under the [sequences-and-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequences-and-series).  In this case, it may be helpful to include the [finance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance) tag because it helps narrow the scope of the question to the types of series used in loan payment questions.

Comment: To add to your example, the tags ([tag:geometric-progressions]) and ([tag:geometric-series]) could be probably even better fit. (A side note - these two tags should [probably be synonymized](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22348/tag-management-2016/25153#25153).)